# Invalid identifier when creating trigger

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, triggers

When I try to create this trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE trigger T25
BEFORE DELETE ON employer
FOR EACH ROW

DECLARE
vnbr number;
BEGIN

SELECT *  into vnbr from employer where role="utilisateu";
if(:old.role=vnbr) THEN

RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20001,'impossible de supprimer ce role');
END IF;
END;
/
```

I get this error :

> PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
>   PL/SQL: ORA-00904: "utilisateu": invalid identifier

Comment: Please read the section "Literals" in the chapter "Basic Elements of Oracle SQL" in the manual: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements003.htm#SQLRF00217

Comment: `vnbr` is a **scalar** variable, not a **collection** variable. So, `select * into vnbr` will fail.

Answer (score 1):

first the literals should be enclosed in `'`

```
SELECT *  into vnbr from employer where role='utilisateu';
```

Also show us the `employer` table it contain only one value?. You are selecting `*` into `vnbr(number)` variable. You should specify the column name from where you are taking and inserting into `vnbr`. Also the query will fail if condition is true more than one row because it will return more than one value and you are trying to save it into a one variable.